# Data value pushed to next line when using split-column-data

Tags: xml, ms-word, rtf, bi-publisher

I have tried to use split-column-data to display table dynamically based on XML files in Word built in Oracle BI Publisher. But the each column width are separated evenly and not display by the size of content.

I have stuck on this for a long time and need help so bad, thanks

This is what I got:
[image]

This is what to expect:
[image]

This is my code and XML in RTF template:
[image]

So far I have tried:

1. Table Propeties > Options > Enable "Automatically resize to fit content" (Not working)
2. Under Layout ribbon > AutoFit >  AutoFit content/AutoFit window (Not working)

Answer (score 0):

Didd you try to select the column - then *Table Properties* - select tab *Column* - check *Prefered width* - increase the width value - press OK.

[image]

Regards...

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but its not working for me. I believe its due to dynamic column. Anyway to display the table column width with the numbers of character in the cell?

Comment: @distinguisedman Well if data is too long ... There are limitations depending on page size, table/column/cell size and font size. You can manage that but there are still some data with number of characters that will not fit in. Regards...